# Marketing Cloud SOAP API SimpleOperator (IN) - Filter on Automation Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to GET all Automations within a Marketing Cloud Environment by using a SimpleOperator on the Status field. The reason I am going through the trouble of adding a SimpleOperator Filter is due to the MC SOAP API requiring it in order to access the object.

Also to note in the Documentation: The only supported operators for the Automation object are: IN, EQUALS. Complex filter is not supported.

This is my Payload Request:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
        <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Automation</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ProgramID</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>Description</Properties>
            <Properties>RecurrenceID</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>IsActive</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
             <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Property>Status</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>IN</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8</Value>
            </Filter> 
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The common error occuring is: "Error Message: No Rows were Found"

If I change it so that the Value = `<Value>2</Value>` I get results.

If I change the value so that it = `<Value>5</Value>` I get results...
(can confirm that there are records that would meet the criteria)

This is what I have tried:

```xml
<Value>1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8</Value>
<Value>"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"</Value>
<Value>["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]</Value>
<Value>("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")</Value>
```

- Single Quote Marks produce a Syntax Error

How do I format the "Value" tag to retrieve all records?

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED! (with a little help from luck!)

Most Important bit of Code below is the "FILTER". In order to grab all Automations from a Business Unit I needed a way to identify all of them. Since there are only 2 supported Operators (IN & Equals) for this Object, I used the "Status" attribute and added in all available status values.

Available Status Values:

```
-1 = (Program Errored Out)
0 = (Program Errored out during building)
1 = (Program building with activities, schedules, and other elements)
2 = (Program ready to start)
3 = (Program running)
4 = (Program paused from running state)
5 = (Program stopped)
6 = (Program scheduled)
7 = (Program waiting for a trigger)
8 = (Program trigger inactive)
```

Successful Payload:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
        <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ClientIDs>
                <ID>MID_OF_BUSINESS_UNIT</ID>
            </ClientIDs>
            <ObjectType>Automation</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ProgramID</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>Description</Properties>
            <Properties>RecurrenceID</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>IsActive</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
             <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <Property>Status</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>IN</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>-1</Value>
                    <Value>0</Value>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                    <Value>2</Value>
                    <Value>3</Value>
                    <Value>4</Value>
                    <Value>5</Value>
                    <Value>6</Value>
                    <Value>7</Value>
                    <Value>8</Value>
            </Filter> 
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BETWEEN` simple operator for values between 1 and 8 or `greaterThan` and `lessThan`. [All are valid values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/simplefilterpart.htm) for SimpleOperators under simple filter part.

```
<RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
    <Property>Status</Property>
    <SimpleOperator>greaterThan</SimpleOperator>
    <Value>1</Value>
</RightOperand>

<RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
    <Property>Status</Property>
    <SimpleOperator>lessThan</SimpleOperator>
    <Value>8</Value>
</RightOperand>
```

Comment: Hi Jackson,

Thanks for the comment.

When Posting to the ObjectType=Automation the documentation states that only "IN OR EQUALS" SimpleOperators are the only supported operators. (It also states ComplexFilters are also not supported)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automation.htm